# make a countdown timer

Tags: java, android

I want to make a countdown timer of New year from current time in android...

```
Calendar thatDay = Calendar.getInstance();
thatDay.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,1);
thatDay.set(Calendar.MONTH,0); // 0-11 so 1 less
thatDay.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2014);

Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
long diff =  thatDay.getTimeInMillis() - today.getTimeInMillis();
```

Now how to convert this **diff** into day,hour,minute,seconds format? please help

Answer (score 5):

the following code

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class cal {
    public static int SECONDS_IN_A_DAY = 24 * 60 * 60;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calendar thatDay = Calendar.getInstance();
        thatDay.setTime(new Date(0)); /* reset */
        thatDay.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,1);
        thatDay.set(Calendar.MONTH,0); // 0-11 so 1 less
        thatDay.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2014);

        Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
        long diff =  thatDay.getTimeInMillis() - today.getTimeInMillis(); 
        long diffSec = diff / 1000;

        long days = diffSec / SECONDS_IN_A_DAY;
        long secondsDay = diffSec % SECONDS_IN_A_DAY;
        long seconds = secondsDay % 60;
        long minutes = (secondsDay / 60) % 60;
        long hours = (secondsDay / 3600); // % 24 not needed

        System.out.printf("%d days, %d hours, %d minutes and %d seconds\n", days, hours, minutes, seconds);
    }
}
```

produces

```
27 days, 17 hours, 18 minutes and 2 seconds
27 days, 17 hours, 18 minutes and 1 seconds
27 days, 17 hours, 18 minutes and 0 seconds
27 days, 17 hours, 17 minutes and 59 seconds
27 days, 17 hours, 17 minutes and 58 seconds
27 days, 17 hours, 17 minutes and 57 seconds
27 days, 17 hours, 17 minutes and 56 seconds
27 days, 17 hours, 17 minutes and 55 seconds
27 days, 17 hours, 17 minutes and 54 seconds
27 days, 17 hours, 17 minutes and 53 seconds
```

hope this is what you want

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
 String formatStr = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";

 SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat(formatStr);
TimeZone obj = TimeZone.getTimeZone("CST");

sdf1.setTimeZone(obj);
Date date = sdf1.parse("your time"); // here put your time zone
long millis = date.getTime();

long currentTimeInMili = new Date().getTime();
MyCount counter = new MyCount(millis - currentTimeInMili, 1 * 1000);
  counter.start();



 class MyCount extends CountDownTimer {
    public MyCount(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    }// MyCount

    public void onPause() {
        onPause();
    }// finish

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        dynamicMatchDesTextView.setText(""+ formatTime(millisUntilFinished)+ " till match start");

    }// on tick

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        onStop();

    }// finish
}

public String formatTime(long millis) {

    String output = "00:00";
    try {
        long seconds = millis / 1000;
        long minutes = seconds / 60;
        long hours = seconds / 3600;
        long days = seconds / (3600 * 24);

        seconds = seconds % 60;
        minutes = minutes % 60;
        hours = hours % 24;
        days = days % 30;

        String sec = String.valueOf(seconds);
        String min = String.valueOf(minutes);
        String hur = String.valueOf(hours);
        String day = String.valueOf(days);

        if (seconds < 10)
            sec = "0" + seconds;
        if (minutes < 10)
            min = "0" + minutes;
        if (hours < 10)
            hur = "0" + hours;
        if (days < 10)
            day = "0" + days;

        output = day + "D " + hur + "H " + min + "M " + sec + "S";
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        Calendar thatDay = Calendar.getInstance();
        thatDay.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,1);
        thatDay.set(Calendar.MONTH,0); // 0-11 so 1 less
        thatDay.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2014);
        thatDay.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        thatDay.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        System.out.println(thatDay.getTime());

        Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
        System.out.println(today.getTime());

        int diffInYears = thatDay.get(Calendar.YEAR) - today.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int diffInDays = ((diffInYears*365) + thatDay.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR)) - today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
        diffInDays--; // Decrementing because I will be taking 1 day (which is 24 hours) to do below hours calculation
        int diffInHours = thatDay.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)+23 - today.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY); // Used 23 hours instead of 24 hours because I am using 1 hour (60 minutes) to do below calculation
        int diffInMins = thatDay.get(Calendar.MINUTE)+60 - today.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        System.out.println(diffInDays + " days " + diffInHours + " hours " + diffInMins +" minutes remaining");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
public String formatDate( long milliSec ) {
        long diffSec = milliSec / (1000);
        long diffMinutes = milliSec / (60 * 1000) % 60;
        long diffHours = milliSec / (60 * 60 * 1000) % 24;
        long diffDays = milliSec / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
        StringBuilder date = new StringBuilder();
        if(diffDays != 0){
            date.append(diffDays).append("D ");
        }
        if(diffHours != 0){
            int length = (int)(Math.log10(diffHours)+1);
            if(length == 1){
                String s = "0"+diffHours;
                date.append(s).append(":");
            }else{
                date.append(diffHours).append(":");
            }
        }else{
            date.append("00").append(":");
        }
        if(diffMinutes != 0 ){
            int length = (int)(Math.log10(diffMinutes)+1);
            if(length == 1){
                String s = "0"+diffMinutes;
                date.append(s).append(":");
            }else{
                date.append(diffMinutes).append(":");;
            }
        }else{
            date.append("00");
        }
        if(diffSec != 0){
           int length = (int)(Math.log10(diffSec)+1);
            if(length == 1){
                String s = "0"+diffSec;
                date.append(s);
            }else{
                date.append(diffSec);
            }
        }else{
            date.append("00");
        }
        return date.toString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int SECONDS = 1000;
int MINUTE = SECONDS * 60 ;
int HOUR =  MINUTE * 60;
int DAY = HOUR * 24;
```

I would start with diff and divide by DAY and then modula by DAY to get the
remainder for the next part.

```
repeat for HOUR, and MINUTE and SECOND
```

Answer (score -2):

SimpleDateFormat: [This will accomplish your goal quite easily.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Simply do the following..

```
SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat... (read the java docs)
fmt.format(your string)
```

No need to re-invent the wheel and make your program larger... This code already exists in Java.

EDIT: Since OP can't read..
S   Millisecond Number  978

Comment: Post do not just answer with a link.  If the link becomes broken, the answer is meaningless.

Comment: maybe Oracle will sell to Microsoft

Comment: Please explain how SimpleDateFormat will convert this diff into day,hour,minute,seconds format?

Comment: No, still not buying it.  There is no SimpleDateFormat constructor which take milliseconds.

Comment: Please stop being illiterate and READ the java doc. "S" is the indicator for milliseconds.

Comment: Actually Colby, it is you who can not read.  I am not the OP, I am simply the guy who downvoted you ;-)  The OP has x amount of milliseconds being the time until xmas (Yay).  How can you use SimpleDateFormat?  I understand very well how SimpleDateFormat formats a Date.

Comment: Why have I been down voted?.. SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss:SSS").format(long) will return exactly what he wants.. I figured he would be smart enough to READ

Comment: So `System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("dd hh:mm:ss:SSS").format(1000 * 60 * 60));` gives a result of `01 10:00:00:000`  - This is wrong

Comment: If you can't figure out how to implement your code after what I've shown you, you should probably just give up.